# Tortoise SVN error while taking code update

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to update my code, when running update command it will ask me for cleanup. When go to cleanup option I get the following error.I am not able to cleanup because of which I am not able to update...I am not able to move forward.
This is the error that I am getting...

"Cleanup failed to process the following paths: K:\ Can't open 'K:.svn\tmp\svn-1CD3FA44': The system cannot find the path specified."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jROHK.png)

Comment: I am not able to cleanup because of which I am not able to update...I am not able to move forward.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov What comment you mean?

Comment: If you need error information..here it is..."Cleanup failed to process the following paths: K:\ Can't open 'K:\.svn\tmp\svn-1CD3FA44': The system cannot find the path specified.